# Replace uppercase character with dot in php

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a string that looks like this:

```
$string = 'helloWorldAndStackOverflow';
```

I want it to end with:

```
$string = 'hello.world.and.stack.overflow';
```

So where I have a uppercase character it should prepend a `.` character. Then I can use `strtolower` on the whole thing.

How can I prepend the dot?

Comment: Add the code which you tried

Comment: You must have tried something right?? I'd either use `preg_match_all` or `strpbrk`

Comment: Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` to identify the `uppercase` and replace that.

```
$string = 'helloWorldAndStackOverflow';
$string = preg_replace('/([A-Z])/', '.$1', $string);
```

After that you can simply use `strtolower`

```
$string = strtolower($string);
```

to convert that into lower case.

Comment: To `lowercase` the string you could add: `strtolower()`:
`$string = 'helloWorldAndStackOverflow';
$string = preg_replace('/([A-Z])/', '.$1', $string);
$string = strtolower($string);`

Comment: yes, I didn't write that in answer because its quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `preg_replace_callback` for replace. try below code,

```html
<?php
$string = 'helloWorldAndStackOverflow';
$dottedString = preg_replace_callback('/[A-Z]/', function($matches){
    return $matches[0] = '.' . ucfirst($matches[0]);
}, $string);
echo $dottedString;
?>
```